# How to call Blazor app from Azure Function

Tags: azure-functions, signalr, blazor-server-side

I have an Azure function app that is using Signalr to send a notification to my server-side Blazor app, however the Blazor app requires cookie-based authentication and is forcing/requiring my Azure function to authenticate. As I understand I should probably use bearer-based authentication but that wont work against the Blazor app. Is there an optimal approach for this?

```
services.AddMicrosoftIdentityWebAppAuthentication(Configuration)
                .EnableTokenAcquisitionToCallDownstreamApi()
                .AddInMemoryTokenCaches();
```

Comment: Are you trying to call your Blazor app in your Azure function. Or you need to authenticate your blazor app using azure function.